# Web scraping with R returning empty

Tags: r, web-scraping

I would like to scrape the movie names from the following webpage: https://www.rottentomatoes.com/browse/in-theaters/, however, the list returned is empty.

The following is my code:

```
html <- read_html("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/browse/in-theaters/")
movies <- html_nodes(html, ".movieTitle")
```

`.movieTitle` is the html class.

Comment: Presumably this is done with a package that you ahve not loaded in your code. There are also "Terms and Conditions" at the website that you have not mentioned how you plan to stay within.

Comment: It looks like the elements of the html you are looking for are loaded through a javascript. Rvest does not automatically trigger javascripts, so if you want to load the html from a HTTP server, rvest will not be sufficient.
You could recur to RSelenium to navigate the page and then capture what you want, but it has a steep learning curve.

Comment: How do I know if the webpage is loaded through javascript?

Comment: You have to inspect the code. Look for calls to *.js cripts or snippets like these: <script type="text/javascript" ; <script src="https://securepubads.g.doubleclick.net/gpt/pubads_impl_rendering_220.js"></script>,

Comment: By the way, the nice ladies at "R Ladies of New York" have a wonderfull tutorial on how to deploy phantomJS to scrape javascript coded pages in R. Check it out: http://www.rladiesnyc.org/post/scraping-javascript-websites-in-r/

Answer (score 0):

I tried using the V8 package:

ct <- v8()
movies <- page %>% html_nodes('.movieTitle') %>% html_nodes('script') %>% html_text()

however the movies variable contains an empty character. Is my code wrong or does this imply that the movie names are not rendered with JS?

Answer (score 0):

Yi Qin, you did not run any JS code within your v8 calls. V8 allows you to run javascript functions inside R, with the results returned as json you need to parse back into R. Look here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/V8/vignettes/v8_intro.html

That said, you can check by yourself if whatever html code you captured through rvest contains what you are looking for.

You could list all the DOM nodes from your captured list ("html")

```
 library(rvest)
 library(tidyverse)
 html <- read_html("https://www.rottentomatoes.com/browse/in-theaters/")
 movies <- html_nodes(html, ".movieTitle")

  html %>% html_structure()
```

You can also write to a local file the captured html list and open the file in a browser:

```
write_html(html, "name_of_file.html")
browseURL('name_of_file.html')
```

Comment: If I'm getting this correct, one can call JS functions within a V8 environment, however when I type ct$eval("document.getElementsByClassName('.movieTitle')") there is an error: document is not defined

Comment: That is because there is no ''.movieTitle" node in the rvest captured 'html' list.  In order to populate the webpage with the nodes that would include ',movieTitle' you would need to execute the Javascript that generates them. My guess is that it is one of these 55: jso <- html %>% html_nodes(xpath = "//script").